# how to add datepicker in custom tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I can't figure out how to add a datepicker (jquery datepicker: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to a custom tooltip.

The way I create the tooltip contents is by concatenating some strings on the fly:
    `contents += 'test1' + '<input type="text" id="datepicker" >';`

The problem is that I need to attach the actual date picker to my input field with id datepicker:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

This doesn't work because contents is not part of the DOM yet.

Any ideas how to overcome this?
Thanks

Comment: Put the `.datepicker` call after where you set `contents`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare

```
var picker = $('<input type="text" id="datepicker" >');
picker.click(function(){
    picker.datepicker();
});
```

And then

```
contents += 'test1';
//domElement is your tooltip content 
domElement.html(contents);
domElement.append(picker);
```

Comment: This is pretty close! Now it displays the entire date picker in the tooltip. What I'd like is for the datepicker to be displayed after the user clicks on the input text.

Comment: In the end I did something similar to what you said: I added a onmouseover tag and called datepicker() on it